# Xamarin.Forms navigate through multiple labels in the same page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write an PDF/Epub reader with Xamarin.Forms.

I managed to get Epub content, showing into a view, scrolling like a web page, all basic stuff. Right now, I wan't to create some kind of page with a right/left slider, just like any other reading app does, but i failed in this task and I have not found a tutorial or project on github that do it.

I want to do something that Adobe Reader already does: You open a file, it fits the page into your screen, when you slide your finger from right to left, you go to the next page, and when you goes from left to right, you go to the previous page. In this app, it looks like some kind of gallery was implemented, but, instead of images, it shows text.

So, any of you know how to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [CarouselPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselPage/) I can see it fits your needs.

Comment: Because in the docs, it is said that CarouselPage would be discontinued.

In the following link, you can see that:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/carousel-page/

Comment: Another problem that I found is the limit that this control accepts. I made a test, that consisted in as the user swiped the screen, a page is added. After 1089 pages, the app crashed. I know that i need to improve the pages management, but this is the limit that I found.

Comment: Well it also says that you can use the CaurouselView instead . 
If I were you i would not load the 1000 pages . 
All what 2 need, theoritically, is two pages (or two views) where one of the views acts as the current book page , and the other one acts as the next/previous book page. and you just change the contents of them based on where do you reached in reading